# Set Plotly Bar Color Based on 3rd Column Value in Python

Tags: python, colors, plotly, bar-chart

I've got the following dataframe called `data`:

```
+----+----------+-----------+---------+
|    |    COUNT | City      | Go_NoGo |
|----+----------+-----------+---------|
|  1 |        1 | Maimi     | False   |
|  3 |      570 | Chicago   | False   |
|  0 |      406 | Denver    | False   |
| 10 |     1220 | New York  | False   |
|  2 |     1557 | Boston    | False   |
|  7 |       90 | Seattle   | False   |
|  9 |        3 | Provo     | False   |
| 11 |      323 | Bismark   | False   |
|  4 |        1 | St. Louis | False   |
|  6 |      562 | Detroit   | True    |
|  5 |     8391 | Fresno    | True    |
+----+----------+-----------+---------+
```

I can make a bar chart just fine:

```
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.update_layout(width = 800, height = 400, template = 'plotly_white',xaxis_title = x_title, yaxis_title = y_title)
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = data['City'].tolist(),
                         y = data['COUNT'].tolist()))

    fig.show()
```

However, I'd like to change the color based on the `Go_NoGo` value ("blue" if true, "red" if false).

I've looked at various ways of adding `marker=dict(color(list(map(set_color,y))))` where `set_color` is :

```
def set_color(value):
     if value:
          return "blue"
     else:
          return "red"
```

I can't figure out how to pass in the 3rd column to set the marker color.

I've already tried various options and it's possible my search-fu isn't sufficient.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use marker_color instead marker. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly_graph_objects as go

def Bar_Color(i):
    
    if (i == False):
        return "red"

    elif (i == True):
        return "blue"

fig = go.Figure()

fig.update_layout(width = 800, height = 400)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x = data['City'].tolist(),
                     y = data['COUNT'].tolist(),
                     marker_color=list(map(Bar_Color, data['Go_NoGo']))
                     )
              )
fig.show()
```

So expected output is Detroit and Fresno are blue and the rest are red.
[image: output figure]